# How to send new and old value when any field is changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the form with a number of input fields, text areas, radio buttons, check boxes. Once value is changed in any field, I should send ajax to my server with field name, **old** and new values. How can I do it?

**Upd.** Here is the current approach:

```
oldValueHolder = null;
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {
  oldValueHolder = this.value; 
});

$('input[type="text"]').focusout(function() {
  if (this.value != oldValueHolder) alert(this.name + ': ' + oldValueHolder + ' -> ' + this.value);
});

$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(event) {
  alert(this.name + ': ' + !$(event.target).is(":checked") + ' -> ' + $(event.target).is(":checked"));
});
```

But I am still not clear how to do the same with radio buttons.

**Upd2.** Here is the solution for radio buttons:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function() {          
  alert(this.name + ': ' + $(this).parents("div.control-group").attr('data-original-value') + ' -> ' + this.value);
  $(this).parents("div.control-group").attr('data-original-value', this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to capture the old value *before* it's changed. One way to do that is:

1. When a object gets focus, get its value in a temporary variable.
2. If the object value is changed, send the new value and old value in ajax.

The **advantage** to this is you're not loading a whole array with *all* values, you've just got a rolling temporary variable that has the value of the last object that received focus. Less memory usage.

**UPDATE**:
Using jQuery to bind a function to the focus event on all inputs of class "myClass", E.g.:

HTML:

```
<input class="myClass" type="text" />
```

JS:

```
myUniversalOldValueHolder = null; // notice this is globally scoped.

$(".myClass").focus(function() {
    myUniversalOldValueHolder = this.value; // "this" is the <input> element, in this context
});
```

...and use `$(".myClass").change()` to define what to do when an element has been changed.

jQuery focus(): http://api.jquery.com/focus/

jQuery change(): http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: Sounds good. How should I look for both events? Can it be one function for all fields?

Comment: Set an event listener for `onfocus` and for `onchange` on the elements that can change.

Comment: Separately for each element? I have ~100 fields.

Comment: If you can make them all members of the same class, then jQuery can do it for you in some very short code.

Comment: Updated to show how to set handlers for all elements of the same class.

Comment: I've used the following code - http://pastebin.com/sG7D49qD, do you see any concerns with `focusout` usage? And, it doesn't work properly with radio buttons (`input[type="radio"]`) and with checkboxes. What should I use with them?

Comment: OK, it is more or less clear with checkboxes, since only two values are possible: `alert(this.name + ': ' + !$(event.target).is(":checked") + ' -> ' + $(event.target).is(":checked"));`

Answer (score 2):

As soon as your form is loaded, loop through all input elements and save their values in an array.

Then, when one of them is changed, look up the old value in the array and send it to the server. When done, update the "old" value with the new value.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to do this, but why not using a `data-original-value` attribute on all input fields that you want to know this?

```
<input type="text" id="txtName"
       data-original-value="Bruno Alexandre"
       value="Bruno Alexandre" />
```

Then upon submit you can send all original values as well with a simple line instead creating on DOM ready for a new array...

---

a **Live Example** based on previous answer: http://jsbin.com/atinel/10/edit

Live example uses this method to attach the current `value` of an input text and show it on the page

```
function saveCurrentValues() {

  $('input[type="text"]')                   // grab all input's that are text
      .each(function() {                    // loop through all of them
        var e = $(this).val();              // get the current value
        $(this)                             // apply everything to the current element
          .attr('data-original-value', e)   // set attribute to the value
          .closest('.row')                  // navigate to the closest element that has a class of 'row'
          .find('span')                     // from there find the 'span' element
          .text(e);                         // set the 'span' element text property to the value
      });  
}
```

Comment: What if user inputs one value (let's say `Somebody Else`), then changed it to another (`Peter Pen`)? What will be sent to the server as old value with last update? Looks like `Bruno Alexandre`, when `Somebody Else` is expected.

Comment: you will reload the data with a page refresh or receive upon sucessfully commit, refresh all inputs with a single call: `$('input type=["text"]).attr('data-original-value', $('input type=["text"]).val());`

Comment: added live example. You just need to call `saveCurrentValues();` when the page is ready and after each successfully form submit.

Comment: Thanks, balexandre, but actually I am looking for different approach - I need to send values of one field to the server when user updated this one field (without waiting for full form submission).

Comment: then just hook up the `blur` event, is that easy!

Comment: balexandre, why `blur` and not `onfocusout`? see update question - I've added there what I currently do

Comment: `focusout` is meant for `live` and `delegate` events because of a flaw in IE.